# Flask sqlAlchemy after disable autoflush and autocommit not working

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-sqlalchemy, I just configure it for no auto flush and no autocommit like this

```
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"autoflush": False, "autocommit": False})
```

But it only work for first session

```
user = User()
user.name = "John"
db.session.add(User)  #No data insert to DB yet
db.session.commit() #user name john inserted
```

but after that

```
fruit = Fruit()
fruit.name = "Banana"
db.session.add(fruit) # <-- this data auto insert into sqlite DB without commit/flush
```

Any idea why i never call session.commit()/flush() the fruit instance already did the insert job ? The Auto Tear Down commit already set to False too

Answer (score 4):

You have to add this option `expire_on_commit=False`

```
session_options={"autoflush": False, "autocommit": False, "expire_on_commit": False}
```

Check out here: [autocommit mode](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#autocommit-mode)

Comment: Found out why, is because my other blueprint page calling the db.session.commit() so the Fruit instance actually is committed from other page. Anywhere thank for answer : )